# clone: operation not permitted using C

Tags: c, linux, namespaces

I'm using Clone() to isolate a process which happens to be a personnalized shell that executes simple commands(ls,echo..). 
In my main, I use the Clone() function to which I pass the namespace flags. Now, it compiles but gives me this error in the shell that's the output of the code I wrote. :

> clone: Operation not permitted.

This is the code :

```
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>

int child(void *args)
{
printf("pid as seen in the child: %lu\n", (unsigned long)getpid());
// unmount all
// chroot (bind mount/pivot root dance)
// mount /proc (make /dev?)
// remove capabilities? or switch user
spawn_bash();
}

int spawn_bash(void)
{
char *newargv[] = { "/bin/bash", NULL };

execv("/bin/bash", newargv);
perror("exec");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main()
{
int namespaces = CLONE_NEWUTS|CLONE_NEWPID|CLONE_NEWIPC|CLONE_NEWNS|CLONE_NEWNET;
pid_t p = clone(child, malloc(4096) + 4096, SIGCHLD|namespaces, NULL);
if (p == -1) {
perror("clone");
exit(1);
}
printf("child pid: %lu\n", p);
waitpid(p, NULL, 0);
return 0;
}
```

I've already searched but all I found was another user here who was working with Docker which is not my case. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Most of the `CLONE_NEWXXX` options you're using require the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability.

Comment: Do I hav to add this capability in C or while running it from the shell?

Comment: The superuser can assign capabilities to programs, similar to creating setuid.